# Multiple bars in Bar plots using R

Tags: r

I have to plot two bar graphs in same barplot. I can do this, I just need help in naming these two things.

Withing R environment in Linux terminal, I write the following commands:

```
data = rbind(c(94,97,100,100,100,100),c(61,80,88,88,92,100))
barplot(data,names.arg=c(10,20,50,100,200,1000),main="Impact of N on trigger/Trojan coverage",xlab="N",ylab="Coverage(%)",beside=TRUE,col=c("darkblue","red"))
```

My question is how do I specify what the blue one means and what the red one means as it is [shown here](http://www.statmethods.net/graphs/images/barplot4.jpg)(blue - 0 and red - 1).

Comment: You're looking for `legend`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the function 'legend'

```
data = rbind(c(94,97,100,100,100,100),c(61,80,88,88,92,100))  
barplot(data,names.arg=c(10,20,50,100,200,1000),main="Impact of N on trigger/Trojan coverage",xlab="N",ylab="Coverage(%)",beside=TRUE,col=c("darkblue","red"))
legend(x="topright",legend=c(0,1),fill=c("darkblue","red"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this excellent [post on Stackoverflow which demonstrates creating a legend in R with identical RGB color values as the plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7948102/create-legend-in-r-with-identical-rgb-color-values-as-plot). This is the code that @Spacedman provides in his solution:

```
plot(1:3,
    col=c("black",rgb(96,123,139, 50, maxColorValue=255),
               rgb(225,64,5, 50,maxColorValue=255)),pch=19)

legend("topright", c("Shuffled", "Riffled", "Somosome"), cex=1.0, bty="n",
   col=c("black",rgb(96,123,139, 50, maxColorValue=255),
      rgb(225,64,5, 50, maxColorValue=255)),pch=19)
```